# Definition System Table On Bizagi

Tags: database, bizagi

What is the definition the system tables On Bizagi: WFCase, WfWorkitem, WfClass and Task.

Answer (score 0):

WFCASE - stores your created case (radNumber) bpmn data (e.g. which process version is used)
WFWORKITEM - related to WFCASE, stores info about task execution time and its status
WFCLASS -  processes properties data
TASK -task properties data